# Set authenticated user's about me/description/summary

Tags: php, youtube-api

I am using the "youtube api" for PHP library, ie zend.

My goal is to set the description, ie what you see when you open the channel of a user in the textbox at the right.

What I did.

```
function anmelden_yt($name,$passwort)
{
$yt_source = 'sou'; //name of application (can be anything)  
$yt_api_key = 'ak';
$yt = null;
$authenticationURL= 'https://www.google.com/youtube/accounts/ClientLogin';  
$httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(  
$username = $name,  
$password = $passwort,  
$service = 'youtube',  
$client = null,  
$source = $yt_source, // a short string identifying your application  
$loginToken = null,  
$loginCaptcha = null,  
$authenticationURL); 
return new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $yt_source, NULL, $yt_api_key); 
}

$yt = anmelden_yt('name','pw');
$yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
$userProfileEntry = $yt->getUserProfile('name');
$userProfileEntry->setAboutMe('test');
$userProfileEntry->setContent('test');
$userProfileEntry->setSummary('test');
```

Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Those fields are no longer exposed via the API. They also don't correspond to the channel description display that you're referring to. There currently isn't a way to set that channel description via the API.

Comment: What's your source for this statement?

Comment: Direct contact with the API's engineering team. I am on the YouTube API Developer Relations team.

Comment: Good. So you should know best whether and when it will be reimplemented or why it was removed.